# Can't run Ubuntu because of PXE Boot

Tags: boot, pxe

I wanted to run Ubuntu without install on a computer at school but they have this dumb PXE network service boot and when I turn the computer on, instead of having to press f6, f10 or f12 I get this message asking if I want to boot from the network (which later allows me to install windows 7). But no way to enter bios and choose the order like I usually did on all my computers. So I simply can't run linux...

Anyone can help with that? I would appreciate it very much.
P.S. I have admin rights on windows 7 if that can help disable the pxe

Comment: If the school administrators have disabled selection of boot options, there's little you can do (except ask permission, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I'm with muru in this request permission or even ask them to add a Ubuntu image or any GNU/Linux images like Redhat/OpenSuse.

Also here some thing you may try:

- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd>

  Some PXE boot ROM's allow skipping PXE boot like some Intel networks. If you are lucky they may already left CD boot or USB CD boot before Hard Drive.
- Another option, quiet for technical users (hijack):

  Setup your own PXE server in a tiny/micro machine that have wired network interface like Raspberry Pi. Unplug that PC net cable and place it directly to your micro server, boot through PXE you own customized system, then replug the net cable to network.

  Check [Mini PC invasion: 10 radically tiny computers that fit in the palm of your hand](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2911098/mini-pc-invasion-10-radically-tiny-computers-that-fit-in-the-palm-of-your-hand.html#slide1) and [Can a $50 mini PC replace your desktop? We tested 3 of them to find out](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/can-a-50-mini-pc-replace-your-desktop/)

  If your micro PC is power full enough you may just use it directly, but that to many thing to unplug/replug (keyboard, mouse, network, monitor,...)